Homotopy coherent transformation and totalization
Let $C$ be the category of chain complexes over a field $F$ and $C^\prime$ be the subcategory of chain complexes with zero differentials. If $X:I\to C$ is a functor, there is an induced "homology" functor $HX:I\to C^\prime$.
Now $X$ and $HX$ are levelwise homotopy equivalent (because we are working over a field, see for example here for details) but not naturally, i.e., there is no morphism $X\to HX$ (or the other way) in the functor category $C^I$. But I can view $X$ and $HX$ in the category $\operatorname{Coh}(I,C)$ of homotopy coherent diagrams and in this category (I think) there is a morphism between them (i.e., a h.c. transformation).
By work of Cordier and Porter (building on Vogt's work), the transformation is invertible (up to homotopy) because it is a levelwise equivalence. The homotopy colimit is a functor from $\operatorname{Ho}(\operatorname{Coh}(I,C))$ to $\operatorname{Ho}(C)$ so $X$ and $HX$ have equivalent homotopy colimits.
Question: If $I$ has simplicial shape, we are talking about double complexes and totalization is a model for the homotopy colimit. But the double complex spectral sequence collapses in the case of $HX$, while the one for $X$ need not, so how can the homotpy colimits be equivalent?

The answer is that the double complex does not collapse in the case of $HX$ either. The issue is that you have a coherent simplicial diagram valued in chain complexes with differential zero, rather than a strict one. Such a coherent diagram includes data such as chain homotopies expressing equivalence of double composites, etc, etc, and this data has an impact on the homotopy colimit.
For example, a coherent simplicial object has a chain homotopy $h$ from $d^2$ to 0 as maps from from $C_2$ to $C_0$. If $x$ is a cycle in the kernel of $d$, then $h(x)$ is a cycle in $C_0$ of degree one higher; that's an expression of $d_2(x)$.

Why is $HX$ not strict?

@vap Ah, I see. Whenever you take a strict diagram and replace all the objects by new objects that are quasi-isomorphic but not isomorphic, you are almost certain to end up with a coherent diagram. So either $HX$ is not a strict diagram, or it's probably not equivalent to the original diagram in $Coh(I,C)$.

Since you ended up with an equivalent coherent diagram, I assumed that your definition of $HX$ had to be the former. But if you apply $H$ to the diagram $X$ and get and have no conference information, it would be the latter.

Thanks. Let's say $HX$ is h.c. diagram like you say. Since groups sitting on different degrees don't talk to each other, is it too naive to hope $HX$ splits as a (co)product of several h.c. diagrams? In that case I would expect the hocolim to split too. Perhaps something more can be said if I work in $\operatorname{H}\mathbb{Q}$-$\mathrm{Mod}$ (rational spectra) rather than $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathbb{Q})$?

@vap I guess the point is that groups in different degrees are definitely talking together. For composable maps $f$ and $g$, a h.c. diagram includes $X(f), X(g), X(gf)$, and a chain homotopy $h$ from $X(g)X(f)$ to $X(gf)$. If the differentials in $X$ are 0, the chain homotopy satisfies $X(g)X(f) - X(gf) = dh + hd = 0$, so $X$ preserves composition; but $h$ is still part of the h.c. diagram in the form of a map that changes degree.

Even though I could choose every map $h$ to be zero, that's a different h.c. diagram. As a result, there's not a splitting without further assumptions. This isn't something about chains versus spectra. It's, roughly speaking, the fact that the splitting of chain complexes can't be made completely functorial.

I see, makes sense. Thanks for your help.
